# run chroot within docker

Tags: docker, chroot

I've a commercial app, that is shipped in a chroot environment : the startup script is making the chroot, and starting the exe.

The App is pretty complex, and also for support purposes, I don't want to change the all environment.

Is it possible to run chroot, and start the service in docker ? Or are the two incompatible ?

Comment: Should be fine. Why not try it and ask a specific question if you have problems?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to make a chroot inside a container... but, as mentioned in "[debootstrap inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26406048/6309)", you might need to [run with the privileged mode](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration).

```
docker run --privileged
```

> By default, Docker containers are “unprivileged” and cannot, for example, run a Docker daemon inside a Docker container.
>   This is because by default a container is not allowed to access any devices, but a “privileged” container is given access to all devices.

There was a [huge discussion for requesting docker to support privileged operations](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1916).
So far, it is not happening.

Comment: How would you incorporate this in a supervisor configuration ? :
- I need to make the chroot,
- Then start 3 skripts

Comment: @OpenStove Have a look at https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker which is using a supervisor-like mechanism (I described it in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33119321/6309). You would still need to run the container in privieged mode though.

Answer (score 9):

Option `--cap-add=SYS_CHROOT` should do the job.

Comment: I wanted to add more info, but there's not much more to it. It basically just allows using chroot: https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/advanced/security/capabilities/#step-1-introduction-to-capabilities