# Vim Remap File Paths To Different Directory

Tags: docker, vim, filesystems, containers, neovim

### Background

I am trying to run Neovim in a Docker container.

One issue I am running into is that paths to files in the container are different than they are on the host file system.

Example:

If I want to edit `/etc/passwd` with the Vim container passing in the path `/etc/password` would edit the file in the container not the file on my host. Instead I would have to pass something like `/host-shared-dir/etc/passwd` and run the container with `docker run -v /:/host-shared-dir ...`.

### Question

How can I remap all paths in Vim to treat another directory as the root.

Example:

If I pass the path `/etc/passwd` to Vim, how can I get Vim to actually open the file `/host-shared-dir/etc/passwd`?

Comment: Interesting way to use docker! Normally I want my containers to be completely separated from my host for security reasons. If you mount your hosts / directory to a directory in your docker container, such as /host you may be able to chroot into /host in the docker container. You will have to use privileged mode as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33235940/3209885

docker run --privileged

Comment: ...why not just directly edit the file on the host?  Especially since this question is about system-level config files?

Comment: You're right it is a bit of an odd use for containers. I'm mainly using a container to record the run environment which Neovim and all its plugins need as code. So I can reproduce it if I need to install Neovim on another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:autocmd` to redirect any newly opened buffers ([`:help BufRead`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufRead)) to a file system path that has your root prepended:

```
autocmd BufRead * execute 'edit' fnameescape('/host-shared-dir' . expand('%:p'))
```

Note that this is just a simple demo; you probably want to clean up the existing original buffer, only do this for certain paths, handle filetype detection, etc. For a more complete implementation, you can look at the [file-line plugin](https://github.com/bogado/file-line); it implements something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Start container in privileged and mount host volume "/"

```
docker container run -t -d --privileged -v "/":"/host/" ubuntu
```

Enter container

```
docker container exec -it <container id> bash
```

Then chroot to host

```
chroot host
```

We now have access to all system files with the same host paths.

Comment: But (assuming that Vim is installed in the container under something like `/usr/bin/vim` and not mounted on the `/host-shared-dir`) wouldn't the `chroot` prevent the start of Vim itself (or any other command)?!

Comment: This solution is starting to get weird and messy... but I like the idea of using a docker container to modify its host. In the docker container: we could mount `/usr/bin/` into the `/host` via a `mount --bind /usr/bin /host/usr/bin/`